# Passing data from a window back to ShellViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

Ok I am having issues getting this figured out.  Most of the tutorials I found are either not complete or not explaining the process well enough.

I created a test WPF app with Caliburn.Micro,  The app's primary window (ShellViewModel) has a text box and a button, The button opens a second window with a text box and another button.  When the user adds text in the second window and clicks "send" POCO object is created and should be sent to the first window and displayed in the text box of the ShellViewModel.

I am Not sure where I went wrong, there does not seem to be many articles helping on this subject.

I tried using the following articles for assistance:
https://claytonone.wordpress.com/2014/06/14/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/

https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator

******EDIT - re-programmed the above project following the directions in 
https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator
Below is the code for this project. Note I added a POCO class to store and send the data I want to send to another window, This is more of what my final goal will be in the primary project I am working on.

Issues I am running into now:
1. When I ran the program designed from the tutorial, VS Errored saying there was not a parameterless constructor.  For this, I attempted to add the constructor. Now the program ran.
2.  When I type text into the second window and click send I get a "Null Reference Error", yet if I debug the "ToSend" object is created and populated with the correct data.
[image: Error]

AppBootStrapper:

```
namespace CaliburnMicro
{
    class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private readonly SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

        public AppBootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        }
    }
}
```

ShellViewModel:

```
namespace CaliburnMicro.ViewModels
{
    class ShellViewModel : Screen, IHandle<EventMessage>
    {
        private string _messageBox;
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;


        public string MessageBox
        {
            get { return _messageBox; }
            set
            {
                _messageBox = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MessageBox);
            }
        }

        public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {

        }

        public void OpenWindow()
        {
            WindowManager wm = new WindowManager();
            SecondWindowViewModel swm = new SecondWindowViewModel(_eventAggregator);
            wm.ShowWindow(swm);
        }

        public void Handle(EventMessage message)
        {
            MessageBox = message.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

SecondWindowViewModel

```
namespace CaliburnMicro.ViewModels
{
    class SecondWindowViewModel: Screen
    {

        private string _secondTextBox;
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        public EventMessage Tosend = new EventMessage();

        public string SecondTextBox
        {
            get { return _secondTextBox; }
            set
            {
                _secondTextBox = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SecondTextBox);
            }
        }



        public SecondWindowViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }

        public void SendBack()
        {
            Tosend.Text = SecondTextBox;
            _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(Tosend);
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //I wanted the app to wait a second before closing
            TryClose();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the POCO that I want to send back to the main window from the second.

```
namespace CaliburnMicro.Models
{
    class EventMessage
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the string gets to your `Handle` inside `ShellViewModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is a small example on how to setup `AppBotstraper` with `EventAggregator`.

AppBootstrapper.cs

```
 public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private SimpleContainer _container;

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container = new SimpleContainer();
        _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        _container.PerRequest<ShellViewModel>(); 
    }
    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        var instance = _container.GetInstance(service, key);
        if (instance != null)
            return instance;
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate any instances.");
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
    }
}
```

ShellViewModel.cs

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen, IScreen, IHandle<EventMessage>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public void OpenWindow()
    {
        WindowManager wm = new WindowManager();
        SecondWindowViewModel swm = new SecondWindowViewModel(_eventAggregator);
        wm.ShowWindow(swm);
    }

    public void Handle(EventMessage message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message.Text);
    }
}
```

Note: If you don't know about Conductors in `Caliburn.Micro` I suggest you to read [this](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition). When you use conductors, you are able to start any child `ViewModel` inside the `UserControl` using method `ActivateItem`.

Your `SecondWindowViewModel` stays the same, BUT the `EventMessage` class must be `public class EventMessage` or you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked!!  Do you know of an article that explains each point used in this AppBootstrapper.

Comment: @DwayneB I would suggest to check [this](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) link.

Comment: I am definitely going to read your link, thank you this worked perfect!  Now I need to understand everything in here, not just "what it should say", but now that I know what correct looks like I figure out why

Comment: I m reading through this link and am very intrigued, to say the least. Was your comment a roundabout way to say I should (or could) have used a Conductor of some form instead of the WindowManager?

Comment: @DwayneB Yes! If you have a Main Window, who is always active, but it constantly changes `UserControls` or lets call them `ChildViews`, then you can use `Conductor`, who suits for this purpose perfectly. And If you are using `Screen` in all your `ViewModels` then I too would use `WindowManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, did you set your `DataContext` so that your primary window knows that the ViewModel is the source of your data?

Comment: If your talking about the returned data being shown in the text box, I did confirm the text box is bound to the correct variable in the viewmodel.  I commented out the code of the button event and set the text of the variable to a test string.  The binding between the variable and the text box is working.  Other then that I have not seen anything where we need to set DataContext.

Comment: What I would try are:
1. Both classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged or comparable for Caliburn.Micro (so for example, class PopupViewModel : Screen, INotifyPropertyChanged)
2. The buttons are hooked properly to the methods. So, when the user presses the Send button, the Send method actually runs in the PopUpViewModel class. For debugging, you could even do something like have it print to console when you press Send, so if it does that successfully, you know it is a binding issue.

Comment: I added a messagebox to each button that shows the value of the text boxs so I know the buttons are attached to the correct methods.  I am sure its in how I am using Messaging in Caliburn Micro.  Out of the last 5 tutorials I read, each was implemented differently and more and more complicated.  This is really getting my mild OCD going!

Comment: What about trying adding a variable (called shellViewmodel for example) that refers back to your ShellViewModel in your PopUpViewModel? That way, you can directly change the ReadString (which I am assuming is bound to your textbox in your primary window). In other words, when user types something into the second window's text box and clicks Send, in the PopUpViewModel it calls shellViewModel.ReadString = textBox2.Text;

Comment: If that (or something similar) works, it would point to a binding issue.

Comment: Alternatively if it still does not work, feel free to post the rest of your code (xaml, etc.) and we can take a more detailed look.

Comment: I did not realize you could actually call back to a variable in the original ViewModel. Would this be the accepted practice?  Everything I read tells me to use the messaging system. I miss the days where you created a variable equivalent to the object you want from the second window, then call the second window from the variable and on the close event of the second window return the proper object.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the best practice to use, in comparison to data binding through DataContext (which Caliburn Micro automatically does for you behind the scenes). My personal opinion is that I would try it through a regular WPF app (without Caliburn Micro) so that you can do everything manually, step-by-step, instead of having Caliburn Micro do some things for you and leave other things for you to figure out what has not automatically been done for you. More so, I meant to give it a shot to see if that works or if there is a deeper problem with the app.